# How to create a method which uses T for the execution on a concrete type?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, typeof, icommand

Consider the following:

```
public void StartCommand<T>() where T : ICommand{
{
  var type = typeof(T);
  if (type == typeof(ConcreteCommand))
    ConcreteCommand.Execute();
  else if (type == typeof(AnotherCommand))
    ...
}
```

Of course this can be executed like this:

```
StartCommand<ConcreteCommand>();
```

This is the way I would like to avoid matching types with enums to identify what concrete type I want to call Execute on. In this case I would add if statements for each type to be checked so it's easy to just call StartCommand with the correct type.
I read somewhere, that this is kind of a code smell, but I don't know how to do this in a different manner.
I know, one way or another, I have to do the concretes, be it an enum, the way I've shown or one method for each type.

Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a type parameter to your method and then just simply call the Execute method on the `ICommand` like :

```
public void StartCommand<T>(T command) where T: ICommand
{
    command.Execute();
}
```

and the `Execute()` is declared in `ICommand` and each new Concrete Command will provide implementation of it.

and now you can call it like:

```
ConcreteCommand command = new ConcreteCommand();
StartCommand(command);
```

or:

```
public void StartCommand<T>() where T: ICommand,new()
{
    T command = new T();
    command.Execute();
}
```

and calling code will be :

```
StartCommand<ConcreteCommand>();
```

and `ConcerteCommand` will have definition having a parameter-less constructor so that instance can be created using that inside generic method, as we have applied constraint that generic-type parameter should have parameter-less constructor:

```
public class ConcreteCommand : ICommand
{


}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The problem is further, the class with the StartCommand<T>() method has all the commands setup. It's called from outside. So the calling class neither has knowledge about the instances, nor does it create them. Your third suggestion creates them as called, but they're already setup, so I need the linkage between T and the instance that already exists.
Is it possible that I'm misusing the command pattern, so that this should be done in a completely different manner?

Comment: you don't need to check if it is `T` as we have already applied constraint

Comment: @AlexanderSeeck: If your class has all the commands set up why not just have methods on that class like `ExecuteCommand1()`, `ExecuteCommand2()`, etc. You don't seem to be gaining much from overloading your `StartCommand` method since a new command will require the class to be updated anyway. And the event method looks even more convoluted...

Comment: @Chris is right, if you already know which commands you need to call, then you should not be worrying about making generic

Comment: ´ List<ICommand> commands = new List<ICommand>();
 public void StartCommand<T> () where T : ICommand{
  foreach (var p in commands) {
   if (!(p is T))
    continue;
   p.Execute ();
   return;
  }
 }
´

Comment: @AlexanderSeeck why are you writing this :  ``if (p is T) continue; p.Execute (); return;`` ? can you elaborate why you need that?

Comment: This way I can put every created command, for which I need to type the constructor (there are parameters) anyway, into a list. With if(p is T) I can interate the list to pick the right command I called from outside. It's less code I have to write for every new command. Just call a constructor while adding to the list.
Is that bad design?

And it's if (!(p is T)), sorry for that, edited it